# Override a struct with a char , why got the following result on Intel processor?

Tags: c++, intel, bit

I'm confused by the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

struct bit 
{
    int a:3; 
    int b:2; 
    int c:3; 
}; 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    bit s; 
    char *c = (char*)&s; 
    *c = 0x99; 
    cout << s.a <<endl <<s.b<<endl<<s.c<<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Since a takes 3 bits , b  2 bits , c 3 bits , when i cast this struct to a char* pointer , did i took the `first` 8 bytes or the `last` 8 bytes ?

1. On a Intel 32 bit machine , how will the compiler store an 32 bit integer ?
2. Why i get `1 , -1 , -4` as a result ?

Comment: @AndersK. , no , it's on a Linux machine

Comment: @AndersK. The struct will usually be 4 bytes regardless of packing, since it consists of a single 32-bit integer containing 8-bits of bit fields.  (Of course this is not specified by the standard.  But this is what you will get on any sane implementation on a modern PC.)

Comment: Hmm, so g++ is insane? ;) With `#pragma pack(1)` sizeof(struct bit) yields 1. Doesn't affect the results of course.

Comment: Yeah, "regardless of packing" bit is a bit bold.

Comment: Since when is `cout << ... endl` and `using namespace std;` C? That's C++. -> edit

Comment: I don't think it's advisable to use this kind of memory access in your example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x99 is 10011001 binary is 100 11 001, which looks very much like 1,-1,-4 (in reverse order). And yes, it's 8 least significant bits.

I believe signedness has confused you, so you may want to use `unsigned int` in the struct. If it's not signedness, then please, be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three issues involved here.  The first (already
mentionned) is endianness.  The second is what the size of `bit` ends up
being.  (It will be four bytes on a lot of compilers.)  If it's more
than a single byte, then your `char*` won't access all of it.  And
finally, there is the question of how the compiler lays out the bits,
and where it puts any left over bits.  Some compilers will start by
laying them from the high order bit, and others from the low order bit.
If the compiler does only use one 8 bit `char` for `bit`, then
depending on the order, you might get {[+-]4, 3 or -1, 1} or the
opposite.  Not to mention that when used as a bit field, plain `int` can 
be either `signed int` or `unsigned int` (thus [+-]4 and 3 or -1).  (In
all other contexts, plain `int` is `signed int`, and from a QoI point of
view, that's what I'd expect here, if only for reasons of consistency.)

In general, if you're only goal is to save memory in an in-memory
structure, bit fields are fine.  But they're worthless as soon as you're
trying to match some external representation.

Comment: Endianness is not an issue here, the size of `bit` doesnt' matter at all, the `char*` had no intention to access all of it and I think how compiler lays out the bits is defined by standard and it lays them out the way you declare them. The only part left implementation specific by standard is default signedness of the fields.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Endianness does matter if `sizeof(bit)` is larger 
than 1; a `char` will not access all of the bits of the structure (and
which ones it does access depends on endianness).  And "Allocation of
bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined" (§9.6/1).
In practice, all of the compilers I know lay the bits out in the order
they're specified, starting from one end or the other of a "word" (for
an implementation defined meaning of "word"), but I don't think that
even this is required.

Comment: Endianness doesn't matter in interpreting results, which the OP found suspicious, I wasn't clear enough, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all since you use int thus signing the struct members

```
*ch = 0x00  -> s.a = 0 s.b = 0 s.c = 0
*ch = 0x01  -> s.a = 1 s.b = 0 s.c = 0
*ch = 0x04  -> s.a = -4 s.b = 0 s.c = 0
*ch = 0x05  -> s.a = -3 s.b = 0 s.c = 0
```

Depending on whether you have a Big or Little Endian machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct is more than 1 byte in size because of your use of `int`, but you are trying to assign a 1-byte value to the entire contents of the struct.  That will not work.  Change your struct to use `char` instead of `int`, especially since you are using a `char*` pointer to assign the value.  The total number of bits specified by the struct members should match the byte size of the underlying data type used, eg:

```
struct bit
{
    char a:3;
    char b:2;
    char c:3;
};
```

On a related note, you can use a `union` to avoid the `char*` pointer:

```
union bit
{
    struct
    {
        char a:3;
        char b:2;
        char c:3;
    };
    char value;
};  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bit s;
    s.value = 0x99;
    std::cout << (int)s.a << std::endl << (int)s.b << std::endl << (int)s.c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```